# How to add Indian Standard Time (IST) in Django?

Tags: python, django

We want to get the current time in India in our Django project. In settings.py, UTC is there by default. How do we change it to IST?

Comment: Are you sure it is UTC by default ? The default for django project is `CST` (Chicago Timezone)

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Did you run in further problems?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Change the field `TIME_ZONE` in the `settings.py`.
For the Indian standard time you will need:

```
TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'
```

For more information about the TIME_ZONE in Django you can see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone

Comment: I tries but getting same problem. >>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 24, 20, 6, 30, 425097, tzinfo=<UTC>)

Comment: Did you modify your settings.py and restart the server?

Comment: How did you solve it? I am not able to get it to work

Answer (score 14):

check [django_timezones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)! this may help others too
it consists of all other timezones for references

Answer (score 12):

```
TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

The above settings should work

Comment: `datetime.now()` still prints UTC time for me after these settings

Comment: use timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) for local timzone aware datetime

Answer (score 6):

Use Below settings its worked for me.

```
TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = False
```

Comment: by specifying USE_TZ=False you're not using django timezone support feature anymore. It worked for you maybe because you have your server timezone set to IST

Answer (score 4):

In general, Universal Time(UTC) based on the mean sidereal time as measured in Greenwich, England. It's also approximately equal to mean solar time from Greenwich. If Daylight Saving Time is in effect in the time zone, one must add 1 hour to the above standard times.

Django got all these [timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/) support, The *django.utils timezone* module, just returns datetime based on the `USE TZ` setting, they are simply datetime objects with timezone 'awareness'.

For IST(India Standard Time), which is UTC + 5:30, set `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'` and `USE_TZ = True`, also `USE_I18N = True, USE_L10N = True`, which are [Internationalization and localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/) settings.

For a reference,

```py
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

print(timezone.now())  # The UTC time
print(timezone.localtime())  # timezone specified time,if timezone is UTC, it is same as above 
print(datetime.datetime.now())  # default localmachine time

# output
2020-12-11 09:13:32.430605+00:00
2020-12-11 14:43:32.430605+05:30  # IST is UTC+5:30
2020-12-11 14:43:32.510659
```

refer [timezone settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#time-zone) in django docs for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Jon Answer, If `timezone.now()` still not working after changing the `TIME_ZONE='Asia/Kolkata'`.

Instead of `timezone.now()` you can use `timezone.localtime()`.

Hope it solves.. :)

Answer (score 2):

All the solutions given above are working.

see the code i have used to get my timezone. my timezone is Indian standard time zone.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Please properly format code, [click here to learn how](https://wordpress.com/support/markdown-quick-reference/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `settings.py` to:

```
TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Calcutta'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False
```

This should work.

For more information about the TIME_ZONE in Django you can see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone

Comment: Why is `USE_TZ` set to false

Answer (score 1):

Django stores timestamp so if we just change the `TIME_ZONE` variable Django will handle rest.

```
TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify setting.py and change the time zone to ***TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'***

Answer (score 0):

Keep **TIME_ZONE** = 'Asia/Kolkata' in settings.py file and restart the service from where you are accessing the timezone (server or shell).
In my case, I restarted the python shell in which I was working and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Where can i get the list of time zones supported by this

Answer (score 0):

Simple Change TIME ZONE from 'UTC' to 'Asia/Kolkata' remember K and A is Capital here.

Answer (score 0):

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

for India user time below few lines of code in settings.py file

**settings.py**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = False
```

Don't forget False in USE_TZ

Answer (score 0):

First of all use these settings:

```
TIME_ZONE =  'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Confirm its working on your local time using shell. Log into your shell & try this

```
from datetime import datetime

print(str(datetime.now()))  # '2023-06-14 12:11:50.923150'
```

or

```
now = f"{datetime.now()}"
print(now)  # '2023-06-14 12:11:50.923150'
```

print the string representation of datetime rather than just
`print(datetime.now())`
and compare with your local time.

Answer (score -1):

change TIME_ZONE in settings.py.

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Colombo'  # 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

to check it is working properly.

`python manage.py shell`

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

then just check your time :)

here is [List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) of tz database time zones as per wiki.