# pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'Asia/kolkata'

Tags: python, django

In my project (made in Virtual Environment), when I run the server, it gives me no errors. But when I open the 127.0.0.1:8000 , it gives me an error saying:

```
A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.
```

Had referred the below post to set the timezone to 'Asia/kolkata':-

[How to add Indian Standard Time (IST) in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855357/how-to-add-indian-standard-time-ist-in-django)

It worked fine till yesterday and today I got an error in prompt as:

```
  File "C:\Users\Ajay\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytz\__init__.py", line 181, in timezone
    raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'Asia/kolkata'
```

How to tackle this? (Using Django V2.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Asia/kolkata' needs to be capitalized as 'Asia/Kolkata' in settings.py