# Why django DateTimeField store One day before date than current date in mysql auto_now_add filed?

Tags: python, django

This is the code in my settings.py file, but still i cannot get accurate date when i create any entry in database, it always shows date with time less than 5:30 hours from the current time. Why?

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True 

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: You store it in UTC?

Comment: Dates are stored as UTC in the database and converted to the time zone when retrieved.

Comment: So, how to store in IST?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Indian Standard Time (IST) in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855357/how-to-add-indian-standard-time-ist-in-django)

Comment: No, I already did this as you can see in my code, I want to store IST time in db.

Comment: @SACHINKUMAR: but that does not make much sense. The idea is to store it in an effective format in the database, and *render* it in another timezone. Especially since you can later render it with the timezone of the user, so a user in Germany for example sees it in CET, and a user in Kolkata in Kolkata time.

Comment: But can a user in rest of the world other than India can see it in their timezone format, although i didn't set for that. I only set for Indian time.

Comment: @SACHINKUMAR: no, you should simple change the timezone in the view/template layer.